# Three great circles meet at a point

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

Find a relation between three great circle segments of length $(a,b,c)$ meeting at a point when the sum of integral curvatures of the three triangles equals $ 2\pi $ steridians.

[image: 3sphTriangs]